# Javascript list filter code not working twice on single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to incorporate two filterable Javascript lists on the same page (in separate divs) using example code by W3.

Link here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

The code works on the first filterable list. The code doesn't seem to work on the second list.

I've created a CodePen to display the problem.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmOLVK

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking I might have to adjust the JS to run two different instances of the function. But I don't really know.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Complete JS novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code based on your request. The problem is that you are using the same `id` for the `input` and `ul` tags.

I replaced them with `myInput_#` and `myUL_#` where `#` represents a number that makes unique the id. Also, I'm using `_` for a trick. When you have a `string` you can easily explode it into an array using the `split()` method. So, the trick is that we can extract the number from the input, when is clicked, and then we can use it to select the right `ul` element.

That is why I add `this` in `myFunction` call:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    id="myInput_1" 
    onkeyup="myFunction(this)" 
    placeholder="Search for names.." 
    title="Type in a name">
```

Then in `myFunction`, we receive the `input` and we can get the number from the `input.id` as an `index` like this:

```
index = input.id.split('_')[1];
```

Here you have all the implementation. I also modify the CSS. Here is the [source in codepen](https://codepen.io/teocci/pen/BRQxOX)

```js
function myFunction(input) {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, index;
    index = input.id.split('_')[1];
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById('myUL_' + index);
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = '';
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput_1, #myInput_2 {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

#myUL_1, #myUL_2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL_1 li a, #myUL_2 li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL_1 li a.header, #myUL_2 li a.header {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: default;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 12px;
  color:red;
}

h2.fixed {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">
  <h2>This one works</h2>
<input type="text" id="myInput_1" onkeyup="myFunction(this)" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL_1">
  <li><a href="#" class="header">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">C</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="2">
  <h2 class="fixed">This one doesn't (fixed)</h2>
<input type="text" id="myInput_2" onkeyup="myFunction(this)" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL_2">
  <li><a href="#" class="header">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">C</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same id `myinput`. Id needs to be unique. Change it and it should work.

You can modify your function by passing the id as a selector:

`<input type="text" id="myInput1" onkeyup="myFunction('myInput1')" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">`

and

`<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction('myInput')" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">`

and the function:

```js
function myFunction(selector) {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById(selector);
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";

    }
}
}
```

CSS

```css
#myInput,#myInput1 {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

EDIT:

I didn't account for the ul which by the way have the same ID. Here's working pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWBGPE

That should do it:)

Comment: Cheers for the help. Unique ID makes sense. Made those changes and now searching in the bottom input is displaying results in the top.

Have forked the code with the changes. Perhaps I've implemented the code update incorrectly.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWBMMb

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWBGPE works now:) The `ul` ids were the same, causing the same issue as before.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to supply your function with the input's and list's id (which has to be unique for each input and list you use, if you want to refer to them by id's, of course):

```
function myFunction(iID, uID) {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById(iID);
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById(uID);
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

And calling it from within html:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction('myInput', 'myUL')" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you are declaring multiple elements with the same `id`. If you look at the documentation on [id](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp), it is meant to specify a **unique** HTML element. I've provided a working example below, to show what needs to be changed. This is just one way of doing it, there are many other ways to do it, as you can see in other answers.

```js
function myFunction(inputSelector, listSelector) {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById(inputSelector);
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById(listSelector);
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

.myUL li a.header {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: default;
}

.myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

h2 {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">
  <h2>This one works</h2>
<input type="text" id="myInput" class="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction('myInput', 'myUL')" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL" class="myUL">
  <li><a href="#" class="header">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">C</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="2">
  <h2>This one doesn't</h2>
<input type="text" id="myInput2" class="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction('myInput2', 'myUL2')" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL2" class="myUL">
  <li><a href="#" class="header">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">C</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```